# Runtime Error 429; Can't Create Object (Excel 2007)

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

My application is as follows: I am using an Access 2007 Database for data storage and using Excel 2007 as the front end. I am using Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 for ADODB Connection and have referenced the libraries (dlls) needed for this. My code below is in an Excel Module and works on 9 out of 12 machines. The other are getting the "Runtime Error 429" and are failing on line 25 of the code which attempts to create the ADODB Object. Can anyone help me with a troubleshooting plan to figure out what is wrong with these machines? I think it may be a registry issue, but wanted to see what you guys have to say. All machines have XP SP3 OS and Office 2007 Installed. Thank you for any help.

Cross-posted at http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/723189-runtime-error-429%3B-cant-create-object.html

```
Public Sub AccessData()
Dim UserID As String
Dim adoConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim adoRS As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sSQL, ConnSQL As String
Dim IDName As String
On Error GoTo err_handler
10:    UserID = Environ("USERNAME") 
20:    pwd = Worksheets(2).Cells(8, 2).Value
25:    Set adoConn = CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
26:    Set adoRS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
30:    ConnSQL = Worksheets(2).Cells(10, 3).Value
35:    adoConn.ConnectionString = ConnSQL
40:    adoConn.Open
50:    adoRS.CursorType = adOpenDynamic
60:    adoRS.CursorLocation = adUseClient
70:    adoRS.ActiveConnection = adoConn 
90:    sSQL = "SELECT fname, lname FROM Staff WHERE userid ='" & UserID & "'"   
100:    adoRS.Source = sSQL     
110:    adoRS.Open
120:    Worksheets(2).Cells(2, 2).CopyFromRecordset adoRS
130:    adoRS.Close    
140:    adoConn.Close
150:    Set adoRS = Nothing
160    Set adoConn = Nothing
170:    Call GetPlans(UserID)
err_handler:
    MsgBox "The code failed at line " & Erl, vbCritical
End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like you have already attempted some of what's [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828550) and that will ultimately point you to registry or server.  Have you checked whether the error persists even if you use late binding? `Dim adoConn as Object, Dim adoRS as Object` and see if it still happens.

Comment: You are mixing two concepts: to use `CreateObject`, better declare variable as `Variant` and remove references. The other way is keeping `Dim`s and references and using `New ADODB.Connection` instead of `CreateObject`. This can be a [DLL Hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell) problem.

Comment: FYI: `Dim sSQL, ConnSQL As String` does not define both variables as string. vba requires a definition after each variable name. to declare both as a string, you would need `Dim sSQL As String, ConnSQL As String`